# SSIS failed to restore variable value in checkpoint

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am providing a checkpoint in my `SSIS` package. I wrote all query in an variable and use that variable in `Execute SQL Task`. While running the package i found there was some issues in query i wrote and the package fails and eventually it created a checkpoint on failed task.
After that i fixed the query in same variable and used that variable in same `Execute SQL Task`. 
Again i re-ran the package and it starts from the same task where i failed earlier but it is still throwing same error in same task which i already fixed. 
I open Checkpoint's XML file and saw the query inside the variable was not updated in XML file and throwing the same issue which was already solved in variable.

**Now how can i solve this checkpoint issue?**

Comment: If you're starting the package mid-way it may well fail. Run the package from the start.

Comment: so it will be started from mid-way right because i am using checkpoint, it will starts again from the previous failed task right. If i have to start the package from beginning then what is the use of checkpoint ?

Comment: *"it will starts again from the previous failed task right"* No, if the package failed then you need to start the package again; iif its fail its failed. Fixing it while it's in a failure state doesn't fix it as the failure has happened. It would be like plugging a hole in a bucket after all the water has leaked out, and expecting the water to be in the bucket again. You need to refill the bucket

Comment: I completely agree with you but what i am looking for is, if the task failed then because i am using checkpoint, it will start again from the failed task when i restart the package.

Comment: If this is in VS, then just disable the prior tasks. if this is a deployed package, then you need to change the package to review the logging you have (need to) built and then skip the tasks. Personally, however, I would set up a rollback process on  failure, so that the package can be run from the start again.

Comment: And when i restart the package, it again failed in previously failed task though the issue has been solved still query wrote in variable is not updated inside checkpoint XML file. if i delete the checkpoint file, then it is working perfectly fine.